# Decoding large JSON files in C#

Tags: c#, json

While downloading auction data from blizzard (a 6 MB JSON file), on decode, I was able to trace the error to this:

> "Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.\r\nParameter name: input"

How can I change the maxJsonLength to say 20 MB (as some of the JSON I parse can be that large) in the following class?

```
public sealed class DynamicJsonConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");

        return type == typeof(object) ? new DynamicJsonObject(dictionary) : null;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Type>(new List<Type>(new[] { typeof(object) })); }
    }

    #region Nested type: DynamicJsonObject

    private sealed class DynamicJsonObject : DynamicObject
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<string, object> _dictionary;

        public DynamicJsonObject(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
        {
            if (dictionary == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
            _dictionary = dictionary;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder("{");
            ToString(sb);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private void ToString(StringBuilder sb)
        {
            var firstInDictionary = true;
            foreach (var pair in _dictionary)
            {
                if (!firstInDictionary)
                    sb.Append(",");
                firstInDictionary = false;
                var value = pair.Value;
                var name = pair.Key;
                if (value is string)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0}:\"{1}\"", name, value);
                }
                else if (value is IDictionary<string, object>)
                {
                    new DynamicJsonObject((IDictionary<string, object>)value).ToString(sb);
                }
                else if (value is ArrayList)
                {
                    sb.Append(name + ":[");
                    var firstInArray = true;
                    foreach (var arrayValue in (ArrayList)value)
                    {
                        if (!firstInArray)
                            sb.Append(",");
                        firstInArray = false;
                        if (arrayValue is IDictionary<string, object>)
                            new DynamicJsonObject((IDictionary<string, object>)arrayValue).ToString(sb);
                        else if (arrayValue is string)
                            sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\"", arrayValue);
                        else
                            sb.AppendFormat("{0}", arrayValue);

                    }
                    sb.Append("]");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0}:{1}", name, value);
                }
            }
            sb.Append("}");
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result))
            {
                // Return null to avoid exception. The caller can check for null this way...
                result = null;
                return true;
            }

            result = WrapResultObject(result);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool TryGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, out object result)
        {
            if (indexes.Length == 1 && indexes[0] != null)
            {
                if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(indexes[0].ToString(), out result))
                {
                    // Return null to avoid exception. The caller can check for null this way...
                    result = null;
                    return true;
                }

                result = WrapResultObject(result);
                return true;
            }

            return base.TryGetIndex(binder, indexes, out result);
        }

        private static object WrapResultObject(object result)
        {
            var dictionary = result as IDictionary<string, object>;
            if (dictionary != null)
                return new DynamicJsonObject(dictionary);

            var arrayList = result as ArrayList;
            if (arrayList != null && arrayList.Count > 0)
            {
                return arrayList[0] is IDictionary<string, object>
                    ? new List<object>(arrayList.Cast<IDictionary<string, object>>().Select(x => new DynamicJsonObject(x)))
                    : new List<object>(arrayList.Cast<object>());
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Or in the calling method:

```
    public static dynamic DecodeJson(this string str)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });
        dynamic result = null;
        try
        {
            result = serializer.Deserialize(str, typeof(object));
        } catch (ArgumentException ae)
        {
            Log.Output(ae.InnerException.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: It seems as of late every question I post the desrialization class on, someone does a drive-by downvote.  If you have a problem with the question itself, please comment as to what your problem is so that it can be addressed/clarified.

Comment: Not an answer, but since you're using c# you might consider one of the third party json serializers like JIL or JSON.NET which are generally much faster, especially for large files like this.  Using those might require an additional dependency however.

Comment: The error message is very clear about the JavaScriptSerializer property MaxJsonLength. A quick look at the docs had told you the solution. I am not surprised about the downvote

Comment: How to set property of a class ("How can I change the maxJsonLength") is not really good SO question... In addition post include wall of code that is nowhere close to [MCVE]... I'm not really sure why you believe this is high quality post.

Comment: @SirRufo - I had just spent a few hours tracing to this as the point of origin of the problem. I did look at the docs, but it wasn't clear if I could just call that property, or if it had to be initialized in a construct in some fashion. There are no examples of it's usage on MSDN.  Further, this downvote has been happening across every question I post the deserialize class on so it doesn't seem to be specific to the question, but more a hatred for that class. (aka : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298231/extracting-json-from-a-website-and-having-parse-errors )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - that code is actually a valid solution from another stackoverflow post, and is complete and verifiable in a copy/paste method. In addition, I provide an extension which calls it and uses it as it was written. I feel that class is actually an excellent piece of craftmanship, elegant, and concise, where other parsers that 'do the same job' are not pastable in any fashion.

Comment: @SanuelJackson Cite from docs *The value of the MaxJsonLength property applies only when you explicitly create an instance of the JavaScriptSerializer class.* is **very** clear to me. Create an instance - as you do - set the property and use the instance. Takes just 1 minute to test and verify (less time than posting a question here)

Comment: @SanuelJackson please consider actually reading [MCVE], especially "M" part of it. Copy-pasting even the best piece of code from internet does not necessary create minimal example (note that exactly the same code is in another question you've linked to)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov this follows that. The problem is not reproducable without the full context of the issue. This is a small excerpt containing ONLY what is required to reproduce, and verify the issue in the context I am having. Obviously cant paste the blizzard 6 MB JSON file.  Barring that, what would you do to minimize this while still having a complete and verifiable example ?

Comment: Custom class `class Test { public String S;}` with `new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize("{S:\"" + new string('c', 3000000) + "\"}", typeof(Test));` demonstrate the problem perfectly fine. You could even push it all into a single line with `new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize("{S:\"" + new string('c', 3000000) + "\"}",(new {S="aa"}).GetType())`... The point is code sample in the post looks like code dump and does not show effort to minimize it - whether you agree with it or not.

Comment: While that snip of code may or may not work to validate this problem, the minimal code required to ensure that the problem was found (instead of some abstract case scenario as you provided), would be to include as little code from the actual project in question as the problem could have been inside the class which maps out to dynamic values. (aka, memory limit, or whatever).  When asking, I minimize while trying to keep the code that is producing the problem in tact, and extracting just that bit that is required to reproduce the problem in my exact case. Abstract demos do not preserve this.

Comment: The last question I had, was there was a problem in the data itself, and thus is evidence that generating an abstract data set, is not a reliable method to detect or ask about a specific problem. While my title is general to the place the problem was occuring, the question itself contains information such as the source of the json data and size for plausible reproduction (blizzards api is free).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should modify the [JavaScriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The maximum length of JSON strings. The default is 2097152 characters,
>   which is equivalent to 4 MB of Unicode string data.

```
public static dynamic DecodeJson(this string str)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int.MaxValue; // The value of this constant is 2,147,483,647
    serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });
    dynamic result = null;
    try
    {
        result = serializer.Deserialize(str, typeof(object));
    } catch (ArgumentException ae)
    {
        Log.Output(ae.InnerException.Message);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you :)